# How to get Unique Purchase Information

Tags: android, security, uniqueidentifier

a user purchases an App.
I need a unique token of this particular purchase to store it in MY OWN backend server.
And I want be able to fetch this token whenever the user is starting my app on any other android device to recognize him.

I dont want to use In App Payments.

Greetings

Comment: if you need to create unique token try this UUID.randomUUID().toString();

Comment: This is not what I am searching for. Creating a UUID does not help me to recognize if the user has already paid for my app on one of his devices. I want google to ensure me THIS user has paid - and I want to store this piece of information in my server - the way I can authenticate this user by myself - important: on every device he is using.